# Retrieve original/not modified image from home or feed

Tags: image, facebook-graph-api

I retrieve photos from home with this graph API request [https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=home.filter(photos)](https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=home.filter%28photos%29).
Then via the object ID I retrieve the images array that gives me different sizes like this :

```
"images": [
    {
      "height": 780, 
      "width": 1240, 
      "source": "https://fbcdn-sphotos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn2/281028_10151592859979158_562775226_o.jpg"
    }, 
    {
      "height": 81, 
      "width": 130, 
      "source": "https://fbcdn-photos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn2/s75x225/969715_10151592859979158_562775226_s.jpg"
    }
```

Is it possible to retrieve the originally posted image ?
The image retrieved has to have the same checksum then the image posted

Comment: What do you consider to be the "originally posted image" in this case? Isn't the first image in that array what you are looking for?

Comment: I mean the image not modified, with the same checksum then the image posted

Answer (score 3):

That's no 100% guarantee checksum is same, don't do that. Why? Because if you upload a .gif or .png image, Facebook would do conversion to become a jpeg image instead. So even though you upload a 1920*1280 .png image, what you can get is the modified version 1920*1280 .jpeg image.  I have no idea facebook database would keep original image or not, but it's not what you can  do using Facebook API.

Comment: Ya, i just want to show you the example(upload .gif image) which was obviously make sense you can't do checksum.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can get the exact, same image by the checksum that you uploaded to their servers. I would think that Facebook modifies them into certain formats so that the photo experience is consistent across the whole site.

That said, they *could* be keeping a copy of the original photo that was uploaded. But as far as getting access to it via the API or any other way, my best guess is looking at the 'source' according to the Facebook documentation on the [Photo object](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/):

> The source image of the photo - currently this can have a maximum width or height of 720px, increasing to 960px on 1st March 2012

You can fetch it via the API by:

```
/<photo id>/?fields=source
```

Sorry it's not an exact answer, but I hope it helps.

Comment: I can't get how to be sure to retrieve the exact same image then the one uploaded (same checksum).

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand your comment. Are you asking how to check the checksums of the two images to see if they are the same? Or are you asking still how to retrieve the image, if possible, from Facebook?

Comment: I am asking still how to retrieve the image, if possible, from Facebook

Comment: My best guess is my answer. Did you try calling the api like I suggested? If the image returned by the API call didn't work, I'm not sure if you can get the original image at all.

Comment: Even if I upload a JPG 700x700px it seems Facebook modify it

Comment: Yeah, there is no documentation to say any way to retrieve the original image. It's most likely the image goes through a modification process to fit their specifications to save on their servers and display on the site. The only thing remotely close is that Graph API call I mentioned, fetching the Photo object along with the 'source' field.